# STM32L LCD interfacing

Tags: c, stm32, iar

can anyone tell me how to interface with the LCD connected to a STM32L151RD? 
I'm using IAR workbench and the example projects dont produce any results. Also, 
I've gone through the online documentations and tutorials but all of them contain information about the STM32L152xD and not 151 which doesnt have any inbuilt LCD but has an LCD driver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you state in the question the STM32L151RD has no LCD controller. The data sheet only mentions "LCD driver" in the front page headline Feature list. I believe they are using the term 'Driver' in this case as synonymous with 'Controller'.  Without this controller I don't know of any easy way to directly control an LCD using a STM32L151RD.

If you are planning to use the STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Lib software Libray that STmicro supply then unfortunately this assumes there is an LCD controller (that is, you need to use an STM32L152x).

However, may LCDs have embedded controller chips. These allow microcontrollers to drive them through common interfaces such as I2C and SPI. It is also common to find 4-bit an 8-bit parallel interfaces that can bit-banged or memory mapped. If you have an LCD of this type you can use the STM32L151RD.